# Deriving touch points layer of line-polygon intersection in QGIS or PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, point, intersection, overlapping-features

Assume you have polygon and a line that goes though this polygon.

Now I would like to create a separate layer which stores the point geometries of where the line intersects the **outline of the polygon**, so where it enters or exits the polygon.

Is this possible in QGIS 3.x or PostGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In QGIS**

In the Processing Toolbox go to `Vector Geometry > Geometry by expression`.

Set the Input layer to your line layer, Output geometry type to Point, and use the following expression (swap out *"polygon_layer_name"* for the name of your polygon layer):

```
intersection($geometry, boundary(aggregate('polygon_layer_name', 'collect', $geometry)))
```

Answer (score 3):

**In PostGIS**

```
SELECT  ln.id,
        dmp.path[1] AS type,
        dmp.geom
FROM    <line> AS ln
JOIN    <mask> AS ply
  ON    ST_Crosses(ln.geom, ply.geom),
LATERAL ST_Dump(ST_Intersection(ln.geom, ST_ExteriorRing(ply.geom))) AS dmp
;
```

where `type` will be an integer representing the sequence of intersecting points per line; an **odd number** are **entries**, an **even number** are **exits** (with this simple system, a line having *only one* intersection will get `NULL`; use e.g. `COALESCE(dmp.path[1], 0)` to get `0` at least)